# Solving for $x$ in $x(t) = \frac{-2}{3}\cos(10t) + \frac{1}{2}\sin(10t)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

A physics problem is asking me a to find when a weight on a spring crosses the equilibrium point.

The equation of motion given is $$x(t) = \frac{-2}{3}\cos(10t) + \frac{1}{2}\sin(10t)$$

Basically, I need to solve for $t$ when $x(t) = 0$. How do I solve for $t$ in such an equation?

Comment: **Hint** Divide by $\cos(10t)$, as long as $\cos(10t)\neq 0$.

Comment: if you have $a \cos(\omega t)+b \sin(\omega t)=0$ then you take one term to the right hand side and divide both sides by say $\cos$  to get an equation in terms of tangent. Then you solve that equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, $\frac 2 3 \cos 10t=\frac 12 \sin 10t$

So, $$\frac{\cos 10t}{3} =\frac{\sin 10t}4$$

So, $\tan 10t=\frac 4 3\implies 10t=n\pi+\arctan \frac 4 3$ where $n$ is any integer.

So,$t=\frac{n\pi+\arctan \frac 4 3}{10}$

For $n=0,t=\frac{\arctan \frac 4 3}{10}$

Also,  $$\frac{\cos 10t}{3} =\frac{\sin 10t}4=\pm\frac{\sqrt{\cos^2 10t+\sin^2 10t}}{\sqrt{3^2+4^2}}=\pm\frac 1 5$$

$\implies \cos 10t=\pm \frac 3 5,\sin 10t=\pm \frac 4 5$

$\cos 10t\cdot \sin 10t=\cos^210t\tan 10t=\cos^210t\cdot\frac 4 3>0$

So, the sign of $\cos 10t, \sin 10t$ will be same.

Comment: So what's the first value of $t$ where $x(t)$ is zero?

Comment: @Imray, please find the edited answer.

Comment: So when $t$ is $\approx .0927$, the equation should be equal to zero?  But when I plug it the value it's still pretty far from zero.

Comment: @Imray, $x(t)=0\implies  \frac{-2}{3}\cos(10t) + \frac{1}{2}\sin(10t)\implies \frac{2}{3}\cos(10t)=\frac{1}{2}\sin(10t)$, then divide either sides by $2$

Comment: Why am I not getting zero when I set $t = arctan \frac{4}{3}$

Comment: Put $10t=\arctan \frac 4 3\implies \cos 10t=\pm \frac 3 5,\sin 10t=\pm \frac 4 5$

Comment: ok Thanks it works now!

Comment: It's not clear how you went from $\pm \frac{1}{5}$ to the next step... Where did the $tan(10t)$ come from?

Comment: @Imray, sorry for the confusion.Please find the rectified answer.